# Any advantages of enabled mypy `strict_optional?

Tags: python, typing, mypy

Do you see any advantages in enabling the option? Now it's disabled by default and I don't see any benefits in the signatures readability or anything else.

Answer (score 4):

Well, any kind of strict typing checks has its benefits. I always enable this check and annotate any variable that can take `None` with an `Optional[T]` annotation, because this enables `mypy` to catch missing null checks and prevent nasty `'NoneType' object has no attribute` runtime errors.

However, I also understand why people would not want to enable it. Quite a lot of code extensively exploited Python's dynamic nature and it would be tedious to annotate them. Some people might also dislike the verbosity of writing `Optional[]`. For me, the benefits of the check outweighs the nuances, but your mileage may vary.

Since the Python type annotations aims to be "gradual typing", meaning types were not required and you can have partially annotated code, not having too strict default settings might be beneficial for the adoptation of such tools.

Comment: Could you give me an example how are you getting the `'NoneType' object has no attribute` error?

Comment: @imbolc Sorry for the confusion. What I meant was, this check could help you catch potential bugs related to variables that could be `None`. A common problem with nullable variables is when you forget to check whether it's `None` and just proceed to access its attributes, thereby getting the error I mentioned. With the check enabled, `mypy` will warn you when you try to access attributes of a possibly `None` variable without an explicit `is not None` check.

Comment: I found the same behaviour if you just assign `None` without explicitly wrapping it into the `Optional`. Eg linting this function: `def f(x: int = None): return x + 1` produces `foo.py:2: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("None" and "int")                                                                 
foo.py:2: note: Left operand is of type "Optional[int]"`. It would give the same result if I wrap `int` into `Optional`.

Comment: I didn't know that, that's pretty nice! It seems that `mypy` has introduced the `--implicit-optional` flag which automatically adds `Optional` for arguments with default values of `None`, but it only works for arguments and not variables or class attributes. I would personally still prefer explicitly annotating `Optional` for the clarity, but it's just a preference of style.